# Compiling pulses with time dependent $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ control

Tags: simulation, hamiltonian-simulation, adiabatic-model, compiling

I have a Hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H = c_x(t) \sigma_x + c_y(t) \sigma_y$$
and I want to compile a pulse "P" that has both $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ control, with different time dependent coefficients $c_x(t)$ and $c_y(t)$ (Essentially, turn the whole Hamiltonian into a pulse).

All I can find is how to compile the pulse "X" with coefficient $c_x(t)$ and then the pulse "Y" with coefficient $c_y(t)$, but not both.

My code: (for example, $c_x(t) = 5t,c_y(t)=10t$

```python
class MyCompiler(GateCompiler):
    def __init__(self, num_qubits, params):
        super().__init__(num_qubits, params=params)
        self.params = params
        self.gate_compiler = {
            "RX": self.single_qubit_gate_compiler,
            "RY": self.single_qubit_gate_compiler,
        }

    def generate_pulse(self, gate, tlist, coeff, phase=0.0):
        pulse_info = [
            # (control label, coeff)
            ("sx" + str(gate.targets[0]), coeff),
            ("sy" + str(gate.targets[0]), coeff),
        ]
        return [Instruction(gate, tlist=tlist, pulse_info=pulse_info)]

    def single_qubit_gate_compiler(self, gate, args):
        tlist = [0,1,2]     
        if gate.name == "RX":
            coeff = np.asarray([(tlist[i]*5) for i in range(len(s))])
            return self.generate_pulse(gate, tlist, coeff)
        elif gate.name == "RY":
            coeff = np.asarray([(tlist[i]*10) for i in range(len(s))])
            return self.generate_pulse(gate, tlist, coeff)
```